# How to return Transaction id, time stamp on execution of invoke function in chaincode?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I need guidance in returning transaction id, time stamp on the client interface after each invoke function call.

I have found that stub.GetTxID() is used to for getting transaction id, but peer.response only take one argument, so i am not able to return the TxID on the client interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a response object to capture relevant information, marshal it into json and return it back, something like this:

```
 type ChaincodeResponse struct {
      txID string
      time *timestamp.Timestamp
 }
```

and then

```
// rest of the invoke code skipped, here is
// the relevant part:

resp, err := json.Marshal(ChaincodeResponse{
      txID: stub.GetTxID(),
      time: stub.GetTxTimestamp(),
})

// return json representation of relevant information
// in response
return shim.Success(resp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something at the moment that requires all of our transactions to be timestamped. I tried some things based on your code above but I think the api has moved on considerably since 2017.

Currently, I'm adding a `created: stub.GetTxTimestamp()` field to all of the things we're putting on the ledger and then reading them later in any queries. Though I'm wondering if the timestamps are already generated and stored, therefore making this unnecessary - do you know if a timestamp is still automatically stored on each item put on the ledger?